# Search a dbgrid

Tags: delphi, excel-2007, dbgrid

I have delphi 7.

I want to search for data inside a dbgrid

That I have linked to excel using a adotable and a data source.

I have searched the internet and only found how to create a new excel document or how to link the excel document

But I want to search the first column through all the rows

Answer (score 2):

Once the Excel is loaded into the ADOTable, it is just like any other ordinary table.

Better do not search in the grid. Instead, use the `Locate` method of your AdoTable for this.

```
//or using [loCaseInsensitive,loPartialKey] options 
ADOTable1.Locate('FieldName', 'Value', []);
```

You might want to use `DisableControls` and `EnableControls` to avoid the grid refreshing graphically while you locate the values you need, and a bookmark to return to the original position.

HTH

Comment: @user2482023, if it helped you please accept the answer so other people know your question is resolved and maybe can use the same solution. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Locate is the better choice.
Your DBGrid is linked to a ClientDataSet or Query, use de Locate on your DataSource.

MyClientDataSet.Locate( ....
For more details, on your delphi code, select the word Locate and with F1 open you help inside delphi.

Answer (score 0):

```
while not adoquery1.Eof do
begin
  for I := 0 to adoquery1.FieldCount-1 do
  if (enhdbgrid1.Fields[i].value<>null) and (pos(uppercase(edit1.Text),uppercase(enhdbgrid1.Fields[i].Value))>0)  then
  begin
    Found := True;
    enhDBGrid1.SelectedField := enhdbgrid1.Fields[i];
    Break;
  end;
  if found then break;
  adoquery1.Next;
end;
```